# Python hexdump generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the following hexdump generator function. How can I improve it?

```
FMT = '{}  {}  |{}|'


def hexdump_gen(byte_string, _len=16, n=0, sep='-'):
    while byte_string[n:]:
        col0, col1, col2 = format(n, '08x'), [], ''
        for i in bytearray(byte_string[n:n + _len]):
            col1 += [format(i, '02x')]
            col2 += chr(i) if 31 < i < 127 else '.'
        col1 += ['  '] * (_len - len(col1))
        col1.insert(_len // 2, sep)
        yield FMT.format(col0, ' '.join(col1), col2)
        n += _len
```

Example:

```
In[15]: byte_string = b'W\x9a9\x81\xc2\xb5\xb9\xce\x02\x979\xb5\x19\xa0' \
   ...:               b'\xb9\xca\x02\x979\xb5\x19\xa0\xb9\xca\x02\x979' \
   ...:               b'\xb5\x19\xa0\xb9\xca\x8c\x969\xfb\x89\x8e\xb9' \
   ...:               b'\nj\xb19\x81\x18\x84\xb9\x95j\xb19\x81\x18\x84' \
   ...:               b'\xb9\x95j\xb19\x81\x18\x84\xb9\x95j\xb19\x81\x18' \
   ...:               b'\x84\xb9\x95j\xb19\x81\x18\x84\xb9\x95'
   ...: 
In[16]: from hexdump import hexdump_gen
In[17]: for i in hexdump_gen(byte_string, n=32, sep=''):
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:     
00000020  8c 96 39 fb 89 8e b9 0a  6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9 95  |..9.....j.9.....|
00000030  6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9 95  6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9 95  |j.9.....j.9.....|
00000040  6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9 95  6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9 95  |j.9.....j.9.....|
```

Tested in CPython 3.6 on Windows 10.

Comment: A similar task was solved [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/147225/84718). You may get some hindsight from there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your hexdump implementation looks pretty good.  I have no immediate comments on the implementation.  I will however comment on the implied requirements.

#### Hex Dumper Definition

Most hex dumpers that I am familiar with dump hex as a modulo of the stride length.  The example you show implies that, but that is because your example uses `n=32`, where `32` is an even modulus of the stride length (`16`).  If you pass in different stride lengths, or pass in an `n` that is not an even modulus of the stride, the output doesn't (to my eye) look quite as nice.

So I suggest you consider adding another parameter (let's call it base_addr) which is the address of the beginning of the byte array.  And, then also consider adding fill at the beginning of the dump to allow it to align the dump with an even modulus of the stride length.  Such that:

```
hexdump_gen(byte_string, base_addr=1, n=1, sep='')
```

Would produce:

```
00000000        9a 39 81 c2 b5 b9  ce 02 97 39 b5 19 a0 b9  |  .9.......9....|
00000010  ca 02 97 39 b5 19 a0 b9  ca 02 97 39 b5 19 a0 b9  |...9.......9....|
00000020  ca 8c 96 39 fb 89 8e b9  0a 6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9  |...9.....j.9....|
00000030  95 6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9  95 6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9  |.j.9.....j.9....|
00000040  95 6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9  95 6a b1 39 81 18 84 b9  |.j.9.....j.9....|
00000050  95                                                |.               |
```

#### One way that could be done:

```
def hexdump_gen(byte_string, _len=16, base_addr=0, n=0, sep='-'):
    not_shown = ['  ']
    leader = (base_addr + n) % _len
    next_n = n + _len - leader
    while byte_string[n:]:
        col0 = format(n + base_addr - leader, '08x')
        col1 = not_shown * leader
        col2 = ' ' * leader
        leader = 0
        for i in bytearray(byte_string[n:next_n]):
            col1 += [format(i, '02x')]
            col2 += chr(i) if 31 < i < 127 else '.'
        trailer = _len - len(col1)
        if trailer:
            col1 += not_shown * trailer
            col2 += ' ' * trailer
        col1.insert(_len // 2, sep)
        yield FMT.format(col0, ' '.join(col1), col2)
        n = next_n
        next_n += _len
```

#### Symmetric parameters

The `n` parameter is an offset into the `bytearray`, which specifies where in the `bytearray` to start the dump.  But there is no equivalent end address.

So currently, the dumper always goes to the end of the byte array.  From a symmetry perspective it would seem a good idea to also provide a terminal condition.

Comment: Thanks for your review. I'll definitely implement these ideas.